# Basic Objective C class to return an array

Tags: objective-c

I am new to Objective C and am trying out some basic concepts but hitting a few brick walls

Essentially what I am trying to do is write a class that returns an array when messaged from another class

The class that returns the value would be something like  -

ReturnClass.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface ReturnClass : NSObject {

}


-(NSMutableArray *) getLocation ;


@end
```

ReturnClass.m

```
    #import "ReturnClass.h"

    @implementation ReturnClass

    -(NSMutableArray *) getLocation {
   //do some stuff to populate array
    //return it
        return  latLngArray;
    }
    @end
```

I then wanted to call this in to another implementation in order to harvest the value

SomeOtherClass.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "ReturnClass.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end
@implementation ViewController
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
NSMutableArray *latLngArray = [[getLocation alloc] init];
}
```

I appreciate there is probably a fair bit wrong with this but please be gentle as I am trying to learn :)

Comment: Classes don't return things, methods do.  And you don't alloc methods.

Comment: (You need to go back and find a good description of what "objects" are and study it.)

Comment: Thanks for the constructive criticism and help

Comment: Trust me -- A few hour spent understanding the basic concepts of objects will do you a lot of good.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The call would looke like this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    ReturnClass *retClass = [[ReturnClass alloc] init];
    NSMutableArray *latLngArray = [retClass getLocation];
}
```

This would give you the array produced by `getLocation`.

This code makes a new instance of `ReturnClass` every time it needs the array; this may or may not be what you want, because you cannot keep any state between invocations. If keeping state in `ReturnClass` is what you need, you would have to implement a *singleton* (here is a [link to a question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9119042/335858) explaining a very good way of implementing singletons in Objective C).

Comment: Ah that makes more sense, I need to instantiate before I can call the method - thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You should review your concepts of object oriented programming in general. In particular, do not confuse a class with a method.

In your code, you have to instantiate a `ReturnClass` instance first to be able to call its method `getLocation`.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSMutableArray *latLngArray = [[getLocation alloc] init];
```

For starters, this line misses the mark. You're sending `+alloc` to the name of a method. You should be sending that message to a class, like this:

```
ReturnClass *myObject = [[ReturnClass alloc] init];
```

and then sending messages to the resulting object, like this:

```
NSMutableArray *latLngArray = [myObject getLocation];
```