# objective-c singleton shall store UIimage. Does not work

Tags: objective-c, uiimage, singleton, setter

I have a singleton in place and want to store a `UIImage` in the singleton. Somehow this does not work. I get the Compiler Error: `No visible @interface for 'UIImage' declares the selector 'setPhoto'` 
Interestingly working with my `NSMutableArray` on the singleton works fine.

How can I store a `UIImage` on my singleton to access it later from another class?

#### Singleton.h

```c
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface SingletonClass : NSObject

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *myArray;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIImage *photo;

+ (id)sharedInstance;
-(void)setPhoto:(UIImage *)photo    

@end
```

#### Singleton.m

```c
#import "SingletonClass.h"

@implementation SingletonClass

static SingletonClass *sharedInstance = nil;

// Get the shared instance and create it if necessary.
+ (SingletonClass *)sharedInstance {
    if (sharedInstance == nil) {
        sharedInstance = [[super allocWithZone:NULL] init];
    }

    return sharedInstance;
}

// We can still have a regular init method, that will get called the first time the Singleton is used.
- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];

    if (self) {
        // Work your initialising magic here as you normally would
        self.myArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        self.photo = [[UIImage alloc] init];
    }

    return self;
}

// We don't want to allocate a new instance, so return the current one.
+ (id)allocWithZone:(NSZone*)zone {
    return [self sharedInstance];
}

// Equally, we don't want to generate multiple copies of the singleton.
- (id)copyWithZone:(NSZone *)zone {
    return self;
}

-(void)setPhoto:(UIImage *)photo {
    photo = _photo;
}
```

#### DetailView.m

```c
-(void)sharePhoto:(id)sender {

    SingletonClass *sharedSingleton = [SingletonClass sharedInstance];

    [sharedSingleton.photo setPhoto:self.imageView.image];
    //Compiler Error: No visible @interface for 'UIImage' declares the selector 'setPhoto'

    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];

}
```

Comment: change `[sharedSingleton.photo setPhoto:self.imageView.image]` to `[sharedSingleton setPhoto:self.imageView.image]`

Comment: Something that should be noted is that you're not using a singleton class properly. In Objective-C, the fastest way to use a singleton is through `dispatch_once`.

Comment: I tried `dispatch_once` like stated in the [following thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9119042/why-does-apple-recommend-to-use-dispatch-once-for-implementing-the-singleton-pat) but it did not work. The app hung-up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By invoking `[sharedSingleton.photo setPhoto:self.imageView.image];` you are basically doing this:

```
UIImage *theImage = sharedSingleton.photo;
[theImage setPhoto:self.imageView.image];
```

So you are not calling `setPhoto:` on your `SingletonClass` but on the returned `UIImage`. Seems wrong.

You probably want: `[sharedSingleton setPhoto:self.imageView.image];`.

And then, I'm a little confused about this method:

-(void)setPhoto:(UIImage *)photo {
        photo = _photo;
    }

First, you probably won't need it, since you have a `@property`. Second you set the argument (`photo`) to the variable (`_photo`). Wrong way around?

Answer (score 0):

Change the method to following:

> ```
> -(void)sharePhoto:(id)sender {
> SingletonClass *sharedSingleton = [SingletonClass sharedInstance];
> [sharedSingleton setPhoto:self.imageView.image];
> //Compiler Error: No visible @interface for 'UIImage' declares the selector 'setPhoto'
> [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
> ```

}

With this line `[sharedSingleton.photo setPhoto:self.imageView.image];` you are actually try to find photo property in sharedSingleton.photo which is actually not declared in that and hence it gives error.

Answer (score 0):

In DetailView.m

-(void)sharePhoto:(id)sender {

```
[[SingletonClass sharedInstance] setPhoto:self.imageView.image];
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

}