# How to get a pointer to an instance of a class that is already instantiated from another class?

Tags: c++, objective-c

I have 4 classes(C1, C2, C3, C4) that use class M1.  M1 holds the model and all the data.  M1 may be instantiated by any of the Cx classes if it is not already.  If it is, then I don't want to create another instance of it, just get the pointer to an instance of M1 in existence, so the data can be used there.

How can I do this?  Is there a way to search for an instance of the class?

Comment: C++ or ObjC? They're not the same.

Comment: I had done this before in C++, but don't remember how.  I am programming in Objective-c, but think c++ code would work as well... either way...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the behavior of [the standard Cocoa (pseudo-)singleton implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9119042/why-does-apple-recommend-to-use-dispatch-once-for-implementing-the-singleton-pat):

```
+ (instancetype)sharedInstance
{
    static id sharedInstance;
    static dispatch_once_t token;
    dispatch_once(&token, ^{
        sharedInstance = [[self alloc] init];
    });

    return sharedInstance;
}
```

Have the C*n* classes access M1 only through this class method and you will always be using the same instance.

Other classes can still create their own instances of M1 in the usual way, with `+alloc` or `+new`. (That's why this is a pseudo-singleton.)

This shared access doesn't have to be part of M1's public interface, either. You could just as easily put this into a category method that's only visible to the C*n* classes.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like the Factory Pattern, where you define an additional `MFactory` class, that holds a pointer to `M`, and a getter method `M* getM()`. When the `Cx` classes need the `M` instance, they query `MFactory` for that instance using `getM()`. The instance then is created, if it hasn't been already. What this design may miss is to allow only `Cx` classes to query `MFactory`, but from the description I conclude that this is not a hard requirement here.

Another issue is how to define which `Cx` classes use which `M` instance, thus, which exact factory object they query. This factory class may be a singleton, but then all the `Cx` class sets are going to share the same model (which is probably not your intent). OR, each set may share one model (and thus one `MFactory`). One more possible implementation is to have a factory create the whole `Cx` set and initialize it with the same model object, and make sure that `Cx` are created only via that factory.