# How does dispatch_once manages to run only once?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have been using dispatch_once for shared instances but what i don't understand is how dispatch_once works, why it runs only once.

Comment: Nit check my answer

Answer (score 1):

Low level computing answer.

Different threads that try to access the critical section — the code passed to dispatch_once — while a thread is already in this section are blocked until the critical section completes.

there-can-only-be-one

It should be noted that this just makes access to the shared instance thread safe. It does not make the class thread safe, necessarily.

Answer (score 0):

> dispatch_once() is synchronous process and all GCD methods do things asynchronously (case in point, dispatch_sync() is synchronous)
>
> The entire idea of dispatch_once() is "perform something once and only once", which is precisely what we're doing.

[Source from Kevin Ballard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9119042/why-does-apple-recommend-to-use-dispatch-once-for-implementing-the-singleton-pat)

> dispatch_once that’s used to guarantee that something happens exactly once, no matter how violent the program’s threading becomes

[dispatch_once upon a time](https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/dispatch_once-upon-a-time/)

Comment: This is an answer to what is dispatch_once() and what it does. There is no information for, "How it manages to run only once?"